# Rspec Routing Error, :id=>#User id:nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

I've got `link_to "My Account", edit_user_path(current_user)` working in the browser however Rspec is giving me the following error

```
  1) Can edit user details
     Failure/Error: current_path.should eq(edit_user_path(@user))
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>#<User id: nil, username: "test_user_6", email: "test_user_6@email.com", crypted_password: "cf10df3a34c12b54fd3d99c11395d43ec8f663a48ab8b32917d...", password_salt: "7cZsZhedN2z5Pxbrcl", persistence_token: "59f5a50ac21151f1bc875b5a8b1d14896fb2010dd14dab9e7cd...", perishable_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

The spec

```
  it "can edit user details" do
    integration_sign_up(@user)
    click_link("My Account")
    current_path.should eq(edit_user_path(@user))
  end
```

Running `tail -f log/test.log` returns 200 so I'm guessing it's an Rspec issue?

```
Started GET "/users/565/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-05 17:03:30 +1100
  Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"565"}
Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (1.6ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."persistence_token" = 'ec26b6f501ff97a0f6b467c3caabb7e93a1cf97905194d030b465d3163d846e2fad9dc0ccbfc371e16b920c57634e843f544d7015eb9dbafda5711e6ec7b9018' LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (2.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_flashes.html.haml (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.haml (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 10.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Testing in the browser is successful.

Do I need an Rspec work around or am I doing something wrong?

Given the Rspec error has `id=>#User id:nil` I'm guessing it's Rspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. The `@user` object doesn't have an id, so Rails can't generate a route. Make sure `@user` has an id by either stubbing it or saving the record.

Comment: Thanks David. The issue was how I was how I set up the user `@user = Factory.build(:user)`